# confused about the rendering behaviour of react

Tags: reactjs

I'm confused with a common pattern I find in React.js

Take this simple temperature calculator, where the user inputs a **T** and we set state.

```
class Calculator extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {temperature: ''};  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({temperature: e.target.value});  }

  render() {
    const temperature = this.state.temperature;    
    return (<input value={temperature} onChange={this.handleChange} />);
  }
}
```

Now this is my reasoning of how this works:

1. User inputs and each keypress is an event
2. This is used by handleChange to set the state
3. The component re renders with the new input value

**Question**

But shouldn't this be an infinite loop?

Comment: There's more to it than this, but: Setting an input's value with JS doesn't trigger the `onChange` event.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is called a controlled component. This is when you use the state of your component to be the source of truth for the value of the input (see the [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) for further explanation).

As @DBS alluded to, the `onChange` event is not triggered by the value being passed to it in the React `render` so there is no infinite loop to be triggered. The `onChange` event is triggered by user input events, depending on the input type:

> - When the element is :checked (by clicking or using the keyboard) for <input type="radio"> and <input type="checkbox">;
> - When the user commits the change explicitly (e.g., by selecting a value from a <select>'s dropdown with a mouse click, by selecting a date from a date picker for <input type="date">, by selecting a file in the file picker for <input type="file">, etc.);
> - When the element loses focus after its value was changed, but not commited (e.g., after editing the value of <textarea> or <input
>   type="text">).

Source: [MDN: HTMLElement: change event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event)